# What is this logic component?

Tags: cpu, computer-architecture, register, logical-processor

This is from http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~milom/cse240-Fall05/handouts/Ch05.pdf , slide 9.

[image]

From this diagram, I recognize 0001 as the opcode or ADD. I recognize 011, or 3, as the source register and 101, or 5, as the destination register. I know that the 1 signifies immediate mode or the second operand is directly in the instruction.

From here, I know that the second operand is 11111 or -1 in decimal and that it will be sign extended(SEXT) before being added to the data in the source register.

Does anyone know what the logical component I highlighted does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a multiplexor. If the input on the left side is `1`, it will pass through the immediate value from `SEXT` block, otherwise it will pass the value from the selected register.

Comment: Would selected register be R7? What value would be in R7?

Comment: Not necessarily. This diagram is relevant for the `add immediate` command, when the fifth bit is set to `1`. You should look up different add commands (with the fifth bit set to `0`) in the spec to see how exactly registers are addressed.

Comment: Oh i get. If the fifth bit was 0, then the multiplexor will choose another register as the second operand. Thanks! I was just a bit confused because the slide 8 doesn't show the multiplexor when the fifth bit is 0.